# XlsxWriter при сохранение в Excel - в начало числа добавляется знак одинарной кавычки

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, export

Экспортирую свой словарь courses = [] в excel файл при помощи библиотеки XlsxWriter.

Вот как выглядет словарь:

```
[{'data': '01.01.2014', 'abv': '321', 'contact': '89169662340', 'title': 'Институт права'}]
```

Но в файле .xlsx в таблице - почему то где целые значения, перед числом добавляется одинарная кавычка '.

Там где дата - нету кавычки. Там где название "Институт права" - нету кавычки. А где abv, и contact (целые числа) она появляется: '321 , '8916966...

С чем это связано? И как это изменить. Результат соответсвенно должен быть без лишних символов и кавычек.

Answer (score 2):

Одинарная кавычка добавляется в начале ячейки для того, чтобы excel интерпретировал содержимое ячейки как текст, и не пытался преобразовать в число.

Возможно, Вам поможет параметр **strings_to_numbers**:
http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/workbook.html

Comment: Спасибо! Но проблема сама собой решилась, возможно следствие того что я пересел на Anaconda где более новая версия lxml, либо то что я открываю файл не в LibreOffice а в MS Office. Больше одинарных кавычек нет.